# Ordinal variable with 0.3% of observations in one category - delete, ignore?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit, data-preprocessing

The response variable in my ordered logit model has 5 categories ranging from '1 = strongly disagree' to '5 = strongly agree'. However, only 0.3% of observations fall into category 1 (4 observations out of 1,320). This has created some problems, such as the inability to test the assumption of parallel lines (Brant test) in Stata. Also, treating these 4 observations as missing data changes the coefficients/significance levels of the model significantly, which worries me insofar as 4 observations should not have such a large effect on the model.

Is it appropriate to run the model with the 4 observations set to missing? Or, should I leave the dependent variable unaltered?

Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What if you combine categories 1 and 2? This is commonly done in ordinal scales where one category has very few responses.

Comment: @PeterFlom Thank you for your advice. It is a big help.

Answer (score 1):

In ordinal logistic regression, especially with the proportional odds approach, you do not need to have more than one observation per level of Y.  No harm is done, it's just that you need to combine some categories to assess the proportional odds assumption using most available methods.  But note that some violation of proportional odds does not mean that the proportional odds model works less well than some other models you might use.

Comment: This is a very helpful comment. I will use the 4-level variable to compute the brant test, and leave the 5-level variable as the dependent variable in the full model. Thanks.